# Primary key with ASC or DESC ordering?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a table with a compound primary key where the second column is ordered descending:

```
CREATE TABLE AccountHistory (                                                                                                                                                                           
  AccountNumber BIGINT NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                        
  Ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                
  Memo TEXT,                                                                                                                                                                                            
  ChangeAmount BIGINT NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                         
  PRIMARY KEY (AccountNumber, ts DESC)                                                                                                                                                              
);
```

However, PostgreSQL is saying there's a syntax error at the `DESC` clause.

- Does PostgreSQL really not allow this?
- Does it ever make sense to have a DESC key like this?
- Is my only option to create an additional index with my desired semantics?

Comment: This does not make sense at all. You specify your order when selecting, not when indexing. Also, in order to make use of the index, you need to order by `AccountNumber` first and `ts` second, otherwise the ordering will not be very efficient. To overcome this problem, specify a separate index on `ts` only. However, you cannot specify a sort order on an index, only on selection.

Comment: @Psi You can certainly tell postgresql the order to index the columns, and that can very much make sense in many situations, e.g `create index myindex(AccountNumber, ts DESC)` is valid in postgresql, but I'm not sure if it can be done on a primary key.

Comment: @nos You can specify the order of index columns themselves (e.g. `col B` first, and then `col A`) , but it does not make sense to me at all why you could reverse the indexing order of a particular column. Also I don't see why you would want that, because you want to order on select, not on definition of the index. You can only order either ascending or descending, and this is just reading the index either from the start or from the end (and then backwards), so no need to specify an order at all for storing the index.

Comment: @psi the postgresql [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-ordering.html) explain one common use of using ASC/DESC in a composite index, there are others uses as well - you can't just flat out say it does not make sense.

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be reasonable to do that, as semantically an index in ascending or descending order is the same, but PostgreSQL does not support it. There's no way to control the index order of an index that is auto-created to back a primary key.

PostgreSQL won't let you create one by creating the index manually as a `UNIQUE` index with `DESC` sorting order then creating a declared `PRIMARY KEY` constraint with it using `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX ...`. It will fail with:

```
ERROR:  index "foopk" does not have default sorting behavior
```

I do not know off the top of my head why Pg requires this. Searching the source code for the above error would probably find you a suitable comment.

You can get `PRIMARY KEY`-like behaviour without the constraint metadata just by creating the unique index separately. That might be OK for you.

Answer (score 4):

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90722/is-unique-index-better-than-unique-constraint-when-an-index-with-an-operator-cla

You can create an index like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounthistory_pk_2 on AccountHistory(AccountNumber, ts DESC);
```

but that cannot be PRIMARY KEY on table, although is important for queries like

```
select DISTINCT on (accountnumber) * from AccountHistory
order by accountnumber,ts desc;
```

Test:

```
CREATE TABLE AccountHistory (
  AccountNumber BIGINT NOT NULL,
  Ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  Memo TEXT,
  ChangeAmount BIGINT NOT NULL
);

EXPLAIN select DISTINCT on (accountnumber) * from AccountHistory
order by accountnumber,ts desc;

"Unique  (cost=65.82..70.52 rows=200 width=56)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=65.82..68.17 rows=940 width=56)"
"        Sort Key: accountnumber, ts"
"        ->  Seq Scan on accounthistory  (cost=0.00..19.40 rows=940 width=56)"

set enable_seqscan=false;

"Unique  (cost=10000000065.82..10000000070.52 rows=200 width=56)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=10000000065.82..10000000068.17 rows=940 width=56)"
"        Sort Key: accountnumber, ts"
"        ->  Seq Scan on accounthistory  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000019.40 rows=940 width=56)"

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounthistory_pk_1 on AccountHistory(AccountNumber, ts);

"Unique  (cost=10000000065.82..10000000070.52 rows=200 width=56)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=10000000065.82..10000000068.17 rows=940 width=56)"
"        Sort Key: accountnumber, ts"
"        ->  Seq Scan on accounthistory  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000019.40 rows=940 width=56)"

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounthistory_pk_2 on AccountHistory(AccountNumber, ts DESC);

"Unique  (cost=0.15..60.60 rows=200 width=56)"
"  ->  Index Scan using accounthistory_pk_2 on accounthistory  (cost=0.15..58.25 rows=940 width=56)"
```