# Postgresql : sorted order on a multicolumn primary key

Tags: postgresql, sorting, indexing, primary-key

Consider the following table definition in a PostgreSql database :

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    id bigint NOT NULL, 
    updateRound timestamp WITH time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_data ON data (id, updateRound DESC);
ALTER TABLE data ADD CONSTRAINT pk_data PRIMARY KEY (id, updateRound);
```

This code creates 2 indexes while 1 should be enough. However, I cannot add a sorted order on the primary key definition. And I have a guilty conscience if I leave a table without primary key.

What should be the best approach ?

Edit : PostgreSql multicolumn index ordering for reference : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html

Edit 2 : good explanations in [Primary key with ASC or DESC ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597101/primary-key-with-asc-or-desc-ordering) . However, I know PostgreSql does not accept sorting on the primary key constraint : this can only be done on an index. But when it comes to implementation, PostgreSql produces 2 indexes for the above definition. I wish the first index could be re-used by the primary key constraint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primary key with ASC or DESC ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597101/primary-key-with-asc-or-desc-ordering)

Comment: A PK constrains to UNIQUE NOT NULL but supplies a default for FKs to the table. There is no relational theory reason for PKs. See my answer at the duplicate link. PS (We can obviously expect that) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need that index to support an `ORDER BY`, right?
I cannot think of a `WHERE` condition that would require the second column in descending sort order.

Since both columns are defined `NOT NULL`, the unique index will behave just like a primary key constraint, and it can be used as the target of foreign key constraints.

So unless you have a tool that checks for constraints and fails if it cannot find any, or you need the constraint for an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`, having the index is good enough in my opinion.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking about `ORDER BY` but not only - and I may be wrong. I thought it could also speed up `SELECT` queries such as `WHERE id=X AND updateRound > 'any date'`. Since the index is sorted, the scan should stop on the first entry that does not satisfy the `WHERE` clause. But re-reading the documentation, I do not see any element to support this hypothesis.

Comment: I should not have used `id` as a column name, it is misleading. This column is meant to represent any arbitrary data on which the `WHERE` clause can be applied. (In my real-life case it is a foreign key on another table index).

Comment: The index would work fine with your `WHERE` clause, but so would a normal primary key index.